# Can I create an on-chain view that calls another contract's on-chain view and return it?

Tags: smartpy

I have two contracts `contract_one` and `contract_two`. On `contract_two` I have an on-chain-view defined like this:

```
@sp.onchain_view()
def get(self, id):
    sp.result(self.data.map[id])
```

This view works correctly. Now what I want is to call this view from `contract_one`. Here's what I've tried:

```
@sp.onchain_view()
def get(self, id):
    contract_address = sp.local("contract_address", sp.address('CONTRACT_ONE_ADDRESS'))
    result = sp.local("result", sp.view("get", contract_address.value, id, t = sp.TRecord( data = sp.TString, address = sp.TAddress )).open_some("Invalid view"))
    sp.result(result.value)
```

Although the contract is compiled successfully, I cannot originate it to hangzhounet, getting the following error:

```
 "Http error response: (400) Failed to parse the request body: No case matched:\n...
```

The error then lists several `/kind` reasons.

My question is, what I'm trying to do, is it possible to achieve? Is there another way to do this? My final goal is to call this view with Taquito and get a result.

Comment: What you want to do is very possible. Your problem is unrelated. Also, you should take advantage of SmartPy tests before going to test networks.

Comment: @FFF So do I use a combination of on-chain views or something else like Lamda views for example?

Answer (score 1):

Not too familiar with SmartPy, but this is exactly what onchain views are supposed to do, so it should work.
My best guess (again, I'm a ligo developer and have very little knowledge of SmartPy), is that the `@sp.onchain_view()` decorator in `contract_one` should be replaced by `@sp.entry_point`, as the `get` function in `contract_one` is an entrypoint calling an onchain view, and not a view function.
See this example of calling an onchain view in the smartpy docs:
https://smartpy.io/docs/general/views/#examples-1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am probably missing something, but aren't entry points supposed to have no returns? Meaning that it cannot return an object?

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your intention. Yes. Entrypoints don't have a return, they only make changes to the contract's storage and send out operations.
Onchain views do have a return, but a view has access only to the storage of the contract it lives in, and isn't supposed to be able to call another contract's view. It is strange to me that this even compiled...

Comment: > It is strange to me that this even compiled...

Probably nobody tried this :)

Comment: Well. I didn't think this was supposed to be possible to do, but I've reproduced and deployed: https://better-call.dev/hangzhou2net/KT1EDAebiK5acsWjSx42xqPWbLirm5AkSRtC/code

Comment: @AharonLando you can indeed call on-chain views from on-chain views

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create it. Here is a small working example of what you are trying to do.

```
import smartpy as sp


class contract_two(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init(
            _map = sp.map({
                0: sp.record(
                    data = 'data',
                    address = sp.address('tz1burnburnburnburnburnburnburjAYjjX')
                )
            })
        )

    @sp.onchain_view()
    def get(self, id):
        sp.result(self.data._map[id])


class contract_one(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, contract_two_address):
        self.init(
            contract_two_address = contract_two_address
        )

    @sp.onchain_view()
    def get(self, id):
        result = sp.view(
            "get",
            self.data.contract_two_address,
            id,
            t = sp.TRecord( data = sp.TString, address = sp.TAddress )
        ).open_some("Invalid view")
        sp.result(result)


@sp.add_test(name = 'Test')
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    admin = sp.test_account('admin')

    c2 = contract_two()
    scenario += c2
    c1 = contract_one(c2.address)
    scenario += c1

    result = c1.get(0)
    scenario.show(result)
```

Few things to note:

- Use `_map` instead of `map`, because it conflicts with Python's methods.
- When you are deploying the `contract_one`, make sure to write a valid contract address instead of `CONTRACT_ONE_ADDRESS`
- And, that contract should have this on-chain view you're trying to call.
- I can't conclude the exact cause of the `/kind` error because I'll need the complete log for that.
- No need to define local variables (at least in the example that you've given).
- If you face difficulty calling it with Taquito, raise a separate question. Will try to help with Taquito there :)